# Setting fallback font for SVG

Tags: css, svg, fonts, font-family

In a web application I need to display an SVG (with the help of `<img src="...">` tag), with text in it. The text uses a totally non-standard font, though:

```
<tspan font-family="'WTFHeadlineOT-Black'">Example text</tspan>
```

Browsers fall back to Times New Roman on this, but the customer's wish is that it be Arial. How to force Arial for this particular family?

Note that I'd like to avoid supplying a web font, as it needs to support the whole Unicode scope. I'd like to fall back to the built-in Arial, that in modern OSes covers most writing systems of the world.

Comment: `font-family="'WTFHeadlineOT-Black',Arial,sans-serif"`

Comment: That would be easy in HTML, but in SVG? What element should I attach this rule to? I don't want the whole page suddenly turn Arial adding it to "body", for example.

Comment: That won't happen if you change the `font-family` attribute of a single `<tspan>` element.

Comment: If you are interested in fallback to arial, then you should just use "Arial, sans-serif" in font-family.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Arial then simply use that in the `font-family` attribute. Like [squamish ossifrage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679849/squeamish-ossifrage) suggested for example, `font-family="'WTFHeadlineOT-Black',Arial,sans-serif"`.

There's no 100% guarantee that it'll be Arial in the end anyway, as not all systems have it installed, even if most do. For some good fallbacks see e.g http://www.cssfontstack.com/Arial.

Another possibility is converting the text to paths instead, if the look is very important.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but the answer is not useful, really. I wrote clearly that the SVG is NOT EMBEDDED but included as and `<img>`. I have no control over SVG content because I'm not generating it.

Comment: Not very clear from the question IMHO, but fair enough. The answer in that case is that you cannot control how it looks unless you force every user to install a custom font locally (Arial with the family-name set to "WTFHeadlineOT-Black"). It may also be possible to set the default fonts in the browser, but that's bound to be unreliable.